# mvc:resouces and mvc:annotation does not work together

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

servlet-spring.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/mgis/**" location="/mgis/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller" />
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now, I can not startup my application.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method
 failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid media type "charset=utf-8": does not contain '/'
```

If I remove the `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, then I can start the application , but I can only access the static resources. All the controller does not work.

If I remove both `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and  the `<mvc:resources mapping="/mgis/**" location="/mgis/" />`, then my application will starat, then I can not access the static resouces, but the controller worked.

Comment: Adding <mvc:annotation-driven /> actualy solves your problem with accessing the controllers. The error is something different.

Comment: But I have delete all the controllers,the error is still there.